# I didn't find CDE Dashboard in Pentaho 5.3

Tags: css, pentaho, dashboard, pentaho-cde

I just installed Pentaho 5.3.0.0 on my laptop.
I am learning BI now and get a task on it. But, I found some of elements have changed from one I got on tutorial at campus (the version is similar though), like I didn't found the CDE Dashboard anymore hence I can't arrange my own dashboard with html and css.
The editing menu is lost, I just have one tab with auto-layouts in it. How can I put my own chart in it? It says "Drag and drop files here.", meanwhile in the prior tutorial I can pick my csv file first and determine what attribute I need to show on dashboard.

Do you know what happened to CDE Dashboard menu? Is it does a change?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using Community Edition, for that you have to go to pentaho Market-place and install CDE and CDA pluggin, after installing this pluggin restart Pentaho BI server and you will see CDE option.